# How do I effectively show success/failure without using green/red colors?

Tags: usability

I have to display a table and the last column of the table shows success/failure of that row.

I cannot use green/red as it represents the result of the subsequent operation a success now does not mean it will be a success in the subsequent operation.

Is there any other color pair that inherently signifies true/false? If not, is there any other way (other than color coding) to effectively convey the meaning?

EDIT:
The column will have strings like:

```
code: 1xx
message: <some_string_here>
```

There are some success codes, some failure codes.

Assume 100 to 110 are success codes and 111 to 199 are failure codes.

Now, if there are over 50 rows, it is not easy to quickly filter out success/failure rows.

Comment: Can you show the words "Success" and "Failure" (or another error message) in that column?

Comment: I have updated the question @StacyH

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use check mark ✔️ and a cross sign ❌ to convey success and failure.
If you want to go for color, you could go for a monochromatic palette to indicate progress or some other form of progress indicator.

[image: blue palette]

Also you should never rely solely on color to communicate something to a user because of a potential color blindness.

Comment: +1 for the colour blindness mention